# Adding HTML to Cell Contents via REGEX

Tags: regex, sublimetext

Ive seen this question here and there but cant find one that matches my requirements.

I am importing content into a website and require HTML (`<br>`) line breaks to be added in to the empty lines in my text. I have coppied column content from Calc to Sublime.

I would like to take this (where one empty line should be replaced with `<br>` and 2 empty lines represents the next cell).

```
        some text here some text here some text here some text here

        some text here some text here 

        some text here some text here some text here some text here


        some text here some text here some text here some text here

        some text here some text here 

        some text here some text here some text here some text here


        some text here some text here some text here some text here

        some text here some text here 

        some text here some text here some text here some text here
```

And end up with.

```
        some text here some text here some text here some text here
        <br>
        some text here some text here 
        <br>
        some text here some text here some text here some text here


        some text here some text here some text here some text here
        <br>
        some text here some text here 
        <br>
        some text here some text here some text here some text here


        some text here some text here some text here some text here
        <br>
        some text here some text here 
        <br>
        some text here some text here some text here some text here
```

I tried a regex like `a{1}\r`, but Im really out of my zone with this as I've had no experience with regex.

Comment: So, you are using SublimeText3, aren't you? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Well Ive tried some regex example on the net but i have little to no exp with regex and the example kept replacing all empty lines, not just the single empty lines.

Comment: Could you share at least one best attempt?

Comment: a{1}\r
Sorry but Im really out of my zone with this. Ive had no experience with Regex.

Comment: Try `(.)((\r?\n){2})(.)` and replace with `$1$3<br>$3$4`

Comment: Thats done it. Could you explain your answer a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REGEXP:**

```
(?<=.)(?:(\r?\n){2})(?=.)
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=.)(?:(\r?\n){2})(?=.)/m';
$str = 'some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here 

some text here some text here some text here some text here


some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here 

some text here some text here some text here some text here


some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here 

some text here some text here some text here some text here';
$subst = '$1<br>$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
?>
```

**ORIGINAL TEXT**

some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here

some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here

some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here some text here some text here

some text here some text here

some text here some text here some text here some text here

**RESULT**

```
some text here some text here some text here some text here
<br>
some text here some text here 
<br>
some text here some text here some text here some text here


some text here some text here some text here some text here
<br>
some text here some text here 
<br>
some text here some text here some text here some text here


some text here some text here some text here some text here
<br>
some text here some text here 
<br>
some text here some text here some text here some text here
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regex:

```
(.)((\r?\n){2})(.)
```

and replace with `$1$3<br>$3$4`.

**Details**:

- `(.)` - Capturing group 1 matching any char other than a line break
- `((\r?\n){2})` - Capturing group 2 capturing exactly two occurrences (`{2}`) of an optional (1 or 0 occurrences, `?`) carriage return and a newline (the single occurrence is captured into a capturing group 3)
- `(.)` - Capturing group 4 matching any char other than a line break.

The replacement pattern contains backreferences to the above mentioned captures and a literal `<br>` substring.

Note that `\r?\n` can be replaced with `\R` to make the engine match any type of a line break.